# Como inicializar um array nesse construtor?

Tags: c++, construtor, inicialização

Estou tentando inicializar um *array* com 0, porém o compilador está gerando erro, sei que posso inicializar assim também:

```
Constructor() : Value1(0), Value2(0), Initialized(false), vSh(false)
{
    Name[100] = { 0 };  
}
```

Porém, eu acredito que assim seria uma péssima prática, acredito que deve ter alguma outra maneira para inicializar da seguinte forma:

```
class Constructor
{
private:
    char        Name[100];
    int         Value1, Value2;
    bool        Initialized;
    short       vSh;
public:
    Constructor() : Value1(0), Value2(0), Initialized(false), vSh(false), Name(0) {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) e seja feliz, é muito mais C++.

Se ainda quiser usar esta forma vai ter que conviver com esta limitação ou inicializar direto no objeto:

```
char Name[100] = { 0 };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/FillChar.cpp).

Pode fazer o mesmo com os outros membros.

Comment: Poderia utilizar string, porém não é tão rápido comparado a um char array, e eu preciso ter um programa extremamente rápido, qualquer milisegundo a menos já faz a diferença pro meu programa.

Comment: Nem sempre o que parece rápido é de fato. Até os maiores especialistas erram nestas presunções. Quem precisa de velocidade não inicializa membros, especialmente longos a não ser com dado real. Também dificilmente cria uma estrutura que desperdiça memória e prejudica o cache, e que talvez crie *overhead* no uso por ser grande demais.

Comment: Por que não se pode inicializar membros quando se precisa de velocidade, isso atrapalha?

Comment: Claro, qualquer operação toma tempo.

Comment: Mesmo assim, acredito que utilizar string poderia ser pior na questão do desempenho, obrigado por responder novamente as minhas perguntas.